# Outputting PL/SQL query results as tabbed result sets while using variables

Tags: plsql, constants, resultset, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to do something that seems simple in PL/SQL Developer but eludes me. If I open a 'SQL Window' and run a series of `SELECT` statements as below, it appears as tabbed result sets in the bottom part of the same window.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE r1 = 'xyz';
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE r1 = 'xyz';
```

However, if I want to declare `'xyz'` as a variable, I have to use a `DECLARE` and `BEGIN-END` block, which means I now have to use `INTO` otherwise it moans. So, I've tried various methods and come up with this:

```
DECLARE
    val VARCHAR(10) := 'xyz';
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE r1 = val;
    CURSOR c2 IS SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE r1 = val;
    TYPE c1_type IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE c2_type IS TABLE OF c2%ROWTYPE;
    rec1 c1_type;
    rec2 c2_type;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO rec1;

    FOR i IN 1..rec1.count LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(rec1(i).col1||' 'rec1(i).col2);
    END LOOP;

    OPEN c2;
    FETCH c2 BULK COLLECT INTO rec2;

    FOR j IN 1..rec2.count LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(rec2(j).col1||' 'rec2(j).col2);
    END LOOP;
END
```

However, this means I have to know all the column names of t1 and t2 and it puts out the results in textual format rather than the nice output table in the bottom part of the window.

Is there an easy way of doing this so that the results appear as tabbed result sets in the bottom part of the SQL Window and still allow me to declare variables to use throughout the query?

Comment: SQL Window of what editor you are referring to, SQL*PLUS or..?

Comment: Sorry, it's in PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Your final goal is still pretty vague, though.  PL/SQL block wont produce query-similar output. It simply not what it was designed for. If you need to run those two queries with different values for the right side of the `r1 = 'xyz'` predicate, or the same values(to eliminate repetitive work), use substitution variables - `r1 = '&variable_name'`. You'll be prompt for an actual value for `&variable_name`. In SQL*PLUS though, to run those two query simultaneously, you would have to define substitution variable explicitly using `DEFINE` command.

Comment: Ah, OK, the `&variable_name` works and the values entered the first time are retained for subsequent runs of the query in the same session. Is there any way of coding this in at the top, though, just so it's obvious to other users of the format and context instead of getting a "random" prompt? Or is that a good reason why I should install SQL*PLUS and use the `DEFINE` command?